# Understanding the shape of a numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

If the array `x` is declared as:

```
x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

the shape of `x` is `(2, 2)` because it is a 2x2 matrix.

However, for a 1-dimensional vector, such as:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

why does the shape of `x` gives `(3,)` and not `(1,3)`?

Is it my mistake to understand the shape as `(row, column)`?

Comment: ``[1,2,3]`` is 1-dimensional, ``[[1,2],[3,4]]`` is 2-dimensional. Compare ``[[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]]]``. "(row, column)" describes a matrix, not an n-dimensional array.

Comment: Your only "*mistake*" is confining your thinking to matrixes (2x2 arrays). In that case yes, you can think of it as 2 rows and 2 columns, but what if you have 63 dimensions? Rows and columns don't have much meaning. More simply, a 1-dimensional vector doesn't have rows, just elements. It is not the same as a 1x3 array

Comment: As a general understanding rule, you can think of it as the number of levels of brackets represents the amount of numbers in the `shape`, and the number itself is how many elements are inside each corresponding set of brackets

Comment: Because it has only 1 dimension

Answer (score 5):

Because `np.array([1,2,3])` is one-dimensional array. `(3,)` means that this is single dimension with three elements.

`(1,3)` means that this is a two-dimensional array.
If you use `reshape()` method on the array, and give it arguments `(1,3)`, additional brackets will be added to it.

```
>>> np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(1,3)
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: aha the reason the vector returns (3,)is because it is just an one dimension! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

`np.array` represents an n-dimensional array. This may include a 2-dimensional array to represent a matrix, for which `(row, column)` is appropriate. It may *also* include 1-dimensional, 3-dimensional or other arrays for which `(row, column)` are too many/few dimensions. Compare:

```py
>>> # 1-dimensional
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]).shape
(3,)
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3])[1]
2
>>> # 2-dimensional
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3]]).shape
(1, 3)
>>> np.array([[1, 2, 3]])[0,1]
2
>>> np.array([[1], [2], [3]]).shape
(3, 1)
>>> np.array([[1], [2], [3]])[1, 0]
2
>>> # 3-dimensional
>>> np.array([[[1, 2, 3]]]).shape
(1, 1, 3)
>>> np.array([[[1, 2, 3]]])[0,0,1]
2
>>> np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5, 6], [7, 8]]]).shape
(2, 2, 2)
```

Note how the shapes `(3,)`, `(1, 3)`, `(3, 1)`, `(1, 1, 3)`, ... represent different logical layouts, as exemplified by the different position at which a specific element resides.

Comment: is it okay to understand np.array([[1,2], [3,4]]) returns (2,2) is just a coincidence of (row,column)? actually it means 2 dimensions with 2 tuples?

Answer (score 1):

As [per the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.ndarray.html), `np.array`'s are multidimensional containers. Consider:

```
np.array([[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]]).shape
# (2, 2, 2)
```

Also, [np.shape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html) always returns a tuple. In your example, `(3,)` is the representation of a one-element tuple, which is the correct value for the shape of a one-dimensional array.