# What does (x,) denotes in NumPy shapes?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been struggling to find what exactly does (x,) denote in NumPy shapes? From its appearance, I know it is telling that there are "x" number of columns/elements in the array, which is basically a 1D array.

But my question is what does the COMMA denote after x here (x,)?  I am asking this question because, I am trying to create a DataFrame and it is giving me an error:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (1, 3)
```

My code:

```
price = np.array([10, 8, 12])

df_price = pd.DataFrame(price, 
                        index=(["Price"]),
                        columns=(["Almond Butter","Peanut Butter", "Cashew Butter"]))
```

Could anyone tell me how come this "price" array's shape is (3,1) here?  It is not. It is (3,) -- that is it.

Comment: In generic Python syntax, `(3,)` indicates a tuple with the number 3 as the only element.

Comment: @Oso - `(3,)` is not shorthand for `(3, 1)`. They have the same number of elements, but the first would be 1D and the second is 2D.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm thinking in terms of another library. So the issue here is that the array is transposed?

Comment: Hi @jakub, yes, I know one is 1D and second is 2D. But my question is still there. What does exactly COMMA denote after x here (x,)? Because, I am having troubles creating my DataFrame based on this error:

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (1, 3).


If it is a 1D array, then how come this error is showing it is 2D (3,1)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the shape of a numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63245509/understanding-the-shape-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @Oso, nopes. As you can see from my code. I did not transpose anything. But just created a simple array and tried to put it in a DataFrame.

Comment: Why do you wonder about the meaning of "(x,)", but motivate it with an error showing "(x, y)"?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi unfortunately no. Everyone starts explaining what and how Numpy Arrays work and how do they actually look alike. That is not my question. I am trying to get in to the core of this problem i.e. what exactly this (x,) mean apart from representing 1D array and x number of columns/elements in the array.

Comment: A shape ``(x,)`` doesn't mean anything other than a 1D array of size x.

Comment: @Oso I am trying to figure out the problem if you check my code above in the question. You will see some weird kind of error that is saying that my array is 3x1 lol. That has actually motivated me to get deeper in to this (x,)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi alright, I agree. But what does the error in my question represent then? why does it say my array is 3x1? it is creating a problem for me to make up a DataFrame with this array.

Comment: It doesn't say your array is (3, 1). It says the values in the array have been transformed to a dataframe of (3, 1).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi ah right, I got your point. I am still learning things, so experts like you all have been a great help for me to get out of this problem. I really appreciate that.

Comment: @Prune, I don't think this is really about understanding (3,) shape, but rather about what `DataFrame` does when given a 1d array.  The real question is why, given a (3,) input, the error is talking about a (3,1) input.

Comment: @hpaulj  Thanks for the insight.  Between this and the accepted answer, I see where I misinterpreted OPs intent.  Unfortunately, I can no longer change my votes.  Hmmm ... maybe an insignificant "edit" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When trying to create a Pandas DataFrame from a flat array, the array must transformed to some 2D form, because Pandas DataFrames are almost always 2D.

The issue arises because you have one row and three columns, so the data array is expected to have the shape `(1, 3)`. The `pd.DataFrame` constructor must be adding a dimension to the end of the array and assumes that each item in the first dimension is a row in the DataFrame.

A simple fix for this is to reshape your data array to the number of rows by the number of columns.

```
price = np.array([10, 8, 12]).reshape(1, -1)
```

The `-1` in the `.reshape` call above tells the function to infer the length of that axis.

Comment: oh right. Shall I consider and make a note that Pandas DataFrames always work with 2D and so on arrays and not with 1D or 0D ones?

Comment: The 1D variant of a DataFrame is a `pandas.Series`. You can probably make a 0D Series or DataFrame, but it wouldn't be useful :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of pandas.Series actually. But was building this DataFrame from a Numpy array. So that is why. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The full traceback of your error indicates that `DataFrame` has done quite a bit of processing of your input.

```
In [336]: pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,4),  
     ...:                         index=(["Price"]), 
     ...:                         columns=(["Almond Butter","Peanut Butter", "Cashew Butter"]))      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1653                 blocks = [
-> 1654                     make_block(values=blocks[0], placement=slice(0, len(axes[0])))
   1655                 ]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in make_block(values, placement, klass, ndim, dtype)
   3052 
-> 3053     return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
   3054 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in __init__(self, values, placement, ndim)
    124             raise ValueError(
--> 125                 f"Wrong number of items passed {len(self.values)}, "
    126                 f"placement implies {len(self.mgr_locs)}"

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 3

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-336-43d59803fb0f> in <module>
      1 pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,4), 
      2                         index=(["Price"]),
----> 3                         columns=(["Almond Butter","Peanut Butter", "Cashew Butter"]))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    462                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    463             else:
--> 464                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    465 
    466         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    208         block_values = [values]
    209 
--> 210     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
    211 
    212 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)
   1662         blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]
   1663         tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
-> 1664         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)
   1665 
   1666 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)
   1692     if block_shape[0] == 0:
   1693         raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")
-> 1694     raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
   1695 
   1696 

ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (1, 3)
```

If we don't specify indices, it produces a 1d column frame:

```
In [337]: pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,4))      # (3,) input                                                         
Out[337]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

same as (3,1) input:

```
In [339]: pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,4)[:,None])   # (3,1) input                                                    
Out[339]: 
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

but you wanted a (1,3):

```
In [340]: pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,4)[None,:])  # (1,3) input                                                     
Out[340]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```

`numpy` broadcasting can expand a (3,) array to (1,3), but that's not what `DataFrame` is doing.

Depending on how you look at it, a pandas dataframe can appear to be a transpose of a 2d numpy array.  A Series is 1d, but displays vertically.  And dataframe indexing gives priority to columns.  I've also seen transposes when exploring the connection between the underlying data storage and output of `values/to_numpy()`. The details are complicated.  Notice that the traceback talks about a 'block_manager' etc.

```
In [342]: pd.Series(np.arange(1,4))                                                                  
Out[342]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

> my question is what does the COMMA denote after x here (x,)?

This syntax is generic Python and not specific to Numpy. We add a comma in this situation when we want to create a tuple. You should be familiar with tuples like `(3, 4)`. What if we want to create a tuple with one element, though. You can try `(3)`, but now Python interprets the parentheses as a grouping operator in a mathematical expresion in the same way when we use them like `(3 + 4) * 5`. This means that `(3)` is just the integer value `3`, not a tuple. So we add a comma `(3,)` to create a tuple with a single element.